# Call a method when ng-template is visible

Tags: angular, ng-template

Does ng-template have any events when it is visible or active in the scope
**or** is it possible to execute any method in such way to call it from the container?

```
<ng-template (active/vissible)="callMethod()"> ... </ng-template>
```

(Or)

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="mytemplate" ></ng-container>
```

Comment: Does the template only become visible at some point, or does it also go from visible to not visible?

Comment: it only gets visible at some point It is being used within an ng-tabset

Comment: In that case, the answer given by popStar should work.

Answer (score 3):

One option could be (valid for any DOM object) is via ViewChildren's QueryList's [`changes`](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList#changes). You mark any DOM element (or use it's type) - `<div #myEl></div>`

Assign it:

`@ViewChildren('myEl') myEl: QueryList<any>;`

And subscribe for changes in `ngAfterViewInit` (as earlier AFAIK its not yet created):

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.myEl.changes.subscribe(_ => console.log(_));
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with ngTabset, but this should work with any DOM element

Comment: isn't there any other way to implement it other than a lifecycle hook

Comment: Pretty sure there are other ways. Why you dont want lifecycle hook?

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
public mycondition: boolean = true;   ///according to need make it true or false

<ng-template *ngIf="mycondition"> ... </ng-template>
```

Comment: can I call a method from it ? @Lavkush Gupta I need to call a method when the template is vissible

Comment: Yes Of cause you can call a method

Comment: I do not want to make the view visible/hide with *ngIf I need it to notify to the component that it is active or vissible like an event