# Set input focus every time inside ng-template

Tags: angular

In my app I've an input element which is visible when I click on button and hidden, when I click on another button. I realized this with a simple ng-template. I want to set the focus for this input whenever it becomes visible. I set the `autofocus` parameter to input, but it doesn't work if I toggle the visibility multiple times (the input lost the focus). I've tried alternatives (`ViewChild`, `Renderer2`) described in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790021/angular2-focusing-a-textbox-on-component-load) question, but it doesn't work either.

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="!isInputVisible; else inputTemplate">Input goes here after click!</div>

<button (click)="toggleInputVisibility()">Toggle input</button>

<ng-template #inputTemplate>
  <input type="text" autofocus>
</ng-template>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public isInputVisible: boolean = false;

  public toggleInputVisibility(): void {
    this.isInputVisible = !this.isInputVisible;
  }
}
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ujvrux).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the description of the autofocus attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp), it should only focus on "page load" style functionality, not when content is created/removed.

You can use `@ContentChild` with `this.contentChild.nativeElement.focus()` after it's shown on the page.

You could also subscribe to a `QueryList` from `@ContentChildren` to trigger the focus ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49927271/10747134)).

Answer (score 0):

May be this might help if you are still looking for a solution.
I have used @ViewChild decorator to get he input element and set the focus on it. I am using a delay here to make it async. You may use detect changes as well.

Modified your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lppmyv).